# How to choose a refrigerator?

Tags: refrigerator, compressor

1. what are the features to look for when buying a refrigerator?
2. Such as what capacity is of the compressor? how do I use this information to measure against my usage?
3. Are copper tubing better? What is the next best thing if copper tubing is not available?
4. How many units of electricity does it use in a 24 hr period?
5. what is the best efficiency in refrigerated as far as electricity is concerned?

What are the other things I should consider in choosing a refrigerator for domestic use for a family of five?
Thank you.

Comment: What about the capacity of the fridge section? and the freezer section? do you want a combined fridge/freezer or just the fridge? How much floor space does it need? How much floor space have you got? Can the door be changed to hinge left or right? **So** many questions to sort before you start on the compressor...

Comment: Consumer rating?

Comment: @TonyStewartSunnyskyguyEE75 The problem with "consumer rating" is that there are (generally) two types: "Consumer Reports" - fairly objective (compare specific features objectively + broad survey of owners) but *behind a paywall*, and "Internet Popularity Contest/Amazon-ratings/etc." which, well, ain't that objective.

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Home Improvement. Unfortunately, "shopping" questions are off-topic here. Please [take our tour](//diy.stackexchange.com/tour) so you'll know how best to participate here.

Answer (score 1):

1 features - subjective. Capacity, outer dimensions, ice maker and water, etc. have no right or wrong answers and depend on your specific needs.

2 compressor - information not readily available, in my experience

3 tubing - inside refrigerator information not readily available, in my experience. Outside for water for ice maker - up to you, not determined by manufacturer.

4 and 5 - efficiency - in the USA look for EnergyStar ratings.